# Sorting list with two arguments

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have a problem. I have a function (which is used almost everywhere)

```
       public void Transfusion(PatientQueue patientQ, List<Event> scheduler)
    {
        Console.Write("\n### TRANSFUSION ###\nBefore Transfusion: " + BloodLevel);
        var p1 = patientQ.RemovePatient();            // Take 1st patient from Queue and get him into var p1 
        Console.Write("\tNeed " + p1.BloodUnits + " blood units..");
        // Remodeling of scheduler, making UT units first in scheduler
        SortedByType(scheduler);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPOSORTOWANY SCHEDULER: \n\n");
        ShowScheduler(scheduler);
        for (int i = 0; i < p1.BloodUnits; i++)
        {
            BloodStorageList.RemoveAt(0); // Removes blood Unit from the System
            scheduler.RemoveAt(0); // Removes information about utilisation from Scheduler
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPO USUNIECIU: \n\n");
        ShowScheduler(scheduler);
        BloodLevel = BloodLevel - p1.BloodUnits; // Reduce BloodLevel
        Console.WriteLine("\tAfter Transfusion: " + BloodLevel);
        Sorted(scheduler);
    }
```

Right now let's focus on Scheduler and Sorting. I wnat to SortByType. This is my function(it works ok)

```
        scheduler = scheduler.OrderBy(a => a.Type).ThenBy(a => a.EventTime).ToList();
        foreach (var schedul in scheduler) Console.WriteLine($"{schedul.Type} : {schedul.EventTime}");
        Console.Read();
```

So let's take a look on Console.[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Xie.png)
It looks like in the function everything wokrs Ok, but when I want to proceed on the scheduler things that happends inside the function doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: The sorted outcome by Type and then EventTime would be ```aUT : 2
aUT : 5
BS : 3
QS : 6
WT : 4```

Comment: I've figured out my problem, I made function which returns List<Event> Object and everything works Ok right now. Thank a lot for help. @MichaelPuckettII

Comment: @TyRRRax the reason it works in the function is you're returning a new list.  When you run the linq query, even if you return to list, you're not modifying the original just the new reference.  You'd have to update scheduler with whatever update mechanism you have.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have to separate lists but managed together as one.  In other words, you want the Type to be sorted individually and placed against EventTime which is also sorted on it's own.  One way to do this (which may or may not be the best way I'll admit) is to sort them each into a list and add them back to a newly sorted list that can be managed.

I've made an example where I sort people by name and password.  Obviously Person model is terrible for this example but it's what I already had scratched up so I used it.

In this example I first sort the people by Name and reference it, I then sort the people by Password and reference that.  Finally I make a new list of person and add each person to the list by the sorted name and password.  If this isn't what you're looking or asking for please let me know and I'll delete the answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() { Name = "Mathew", Password = "2345" },
                new Person() { Name = "Mathew", Password = "1234" },
                new Person() { Name = "John", Password = "5678" },
                new Person() { Name = "Mark", Password = "5678" },
                new Person() { Name = "Luke", Password = "0987" },
                new Person() { Name = "John", Password = "6534" }
            };

            var names = people.OrderBy(person => person.Name).Select(person => person.Name).ToList();
            var passwords = people.OrderBy(person => person.Password).Select(person => person.Password).ToList();
            var sortPeople = new List<Person>();
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Count(); i++) sortPeople.Add(new Person() { Name = names[i], Password = passwords[i] });  

            foreach (var person in sortPeople) Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} : {person.Password}");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I really feel there's a linq query that could solve this also but I couldn't wrap my head around it.  Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.